Short Story about a car breaking down in the desert, darts, and maybe cannibals
I read an English textbook many years ago (late 80s, early 90s I think).  In that book, I read a short story and can only vaguely remember a very few details.
There was a family driving down a road through a deserted area (there was no sign of any other people) when a "tick" sound was heard.  Shortly after the car blew a tire and when the man driving got out to check and change the tire, he noticed a dart on the road.
I don't remember much of anything else about it except that at the end the dart was from an indigenous tribe of, I think, cannibals.
For some reason, I keep thinking that the story is set in South or Central America.  And I want to say that the car being driven was a station wagon.  I have looked high and low and googled all manner of ways and have not been able to find it.
If it helps, I want to say that the textbook is also where I first read Metamorphosis and The Cask of Amontillado, so a high school level textbook.

Perhaps "And The Rock Cried Out" by Ray Bradbury, not exact match but I think it's close.

@Ayshe please post this as an answer so I can accept it.  This is what I've been trying to remember for years.  And apparently it continues another story, and it's in a book available on kindle unlimited right now, so I will be... burying.. myself in some Ray Bradbury stories this weekend.

"And The Rock Cried Out" by Ray Bradbury
Description from Goodreads:

A couple find themselves in Uruguay when the US is wiped out in a
nuclear exchange. With American economic and military might
eradicated, husband and wife become the unfortunate focus for years of
subjugation and resentment.

Excerpt:

They drove steadily.
‘Did you see anyone?’
‘No. You?’
She shook her head.
‘You’re going too fast.’
He slowed only in time. As they rounded a curve another clump of the
bright flashing objects filled the right side of the road. He swerved
to the left and passed.
‘Sons-of-bitches!’
‘They’re not sons-of-bitches, they’re just people who never had a car
like this or anything at all.’
Something ticked across the windowpane.
There was a streak of colorless liquid on the glass.
Leonora glanced up. ‘Is it going to rain?’
‘No, an insect hit the pane.’
Another tick.
‘Are you sure that was an insect?’
Tick, tick, tick.
‘Shut the window!’ he said, speeding up.
Something fell in her lap.
She looked down at it. He reached over to touch the thing. ‘Quick!’
She pressed the button. The window snapped up.
Then she examined her lap again.
The tiny blowgun dart glistened there.
‘Don’t get any of the liquid on you,’ he said. ‘Wrap it in your
handkerchief – we’ll throw it away later.’

